# Creating an array of IDs from a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

Im trying to generate an array but not sure how to go about it.

I'm currently getting my data like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail LIKE 'test@test.com'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersettings WHERE userId = ".$row['userId']." AND usersettingCategory".$row1['categoryId']." LIKE 'y'");
    $isyes = mysql_num_rows($query2);

    if($isyes > 0){

        $cat1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shopstateId = 1 AND (categoryId1 = ".$row1['categoryId']." OR categoryId2 = ".$row1['categoryId']." OR categoryId3 = ".$row1['categoryId'].")");
        $cat1match = mysql_num_rows($cat1);

        if($cat1match > 0){
            while($cat1shop = mysql_fetch_array($cat1)){
                $cat1msg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE shopId = ".$cat1shop['shopId']." and messagestateId = 1");
                while($cat1msgrow = mysql_fetch_array($cat1msg)){

                    echo $cat1msgrow['messageContent']." - ".$cat1msgrow['messageCode'];
                    $cat1img = mysql_query("SELECT shopimagePath FROM shopimages WHERE shopimageId = ".$cat1shop['shopimageId']);
                    $imgpath = mysql_fetch_array($cat1img);
                    echo " - ".$imgpath['shopimagePath']."<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

But this can cause duplicates when a user has all 3 of a shops categories picked in their preferences. I am trying to find a way to just pull the message ID out instead of the whole thing and put it into an array giving me, for example:

1,3,5,7,1,3,5,2,4,7,8

Then I can just run a separate query to say get me all messages where the ID is in the array, but i am unsure of the most constructive way to build such an array and examples of array from a while loop I have seen do not seem to be what I am looking for.

Is there anyone out there that can push me in the right direction?

Comment: why dont use! `inner join`, and can you show up the structures of tables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a much easier way to create the required result. I think at 6am after a hard night coding my brain was fried and I was making things a lot more complicated than I needed to. A simple solution to my issue is as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail LIKE 'test2@test2.com'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$categories = "(";

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT usersettingCategory".$row1['categoryId']." FROM usersettings WHERE userId = ".$row['userId']);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);

    if($row2['usersettingCategory'.$row1['categoryId']] == y){

        $categories .= $row1['categoryId'].",";
    }

}

$categories = substr_replace($categories ,")",-1);

echo $categories."<br />";

$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shops,messages WHERE shops.shopId = messages.shopId AND messages.messagestateId = 1 AND (shops.categoryId1 IN $categories OR shops.categoryId2 IN $categories OR shops.categoryId3 IN $categories)");

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){

    $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT shopimagePath FROM shopimages WHERE shopimageId = ".$row3['shopimageId']);
    $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($query4);

    echo $row3['messageContent']." - ".$row3['messageCode']." - ".$row4['shopimagePath']."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with this code. But if you want an array from a query without duplicate result, you can use " select DISTINCT (id) " in your query or for more simple solution :

```
$id_arr = array();
$sql = mysql_query("select id from id_table"); 
while ($id_result = mysql_fetch_array($sql) {
  $id  = $id_result['id'];
  if (!in_array($id, $id_arr)) {
    $id_arr[] = $id;
  }
}
```